# How to get a line of character in text widget in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I've the Text widget that contains:

```
This is the first line
This is the Second line
This is the Third line
```

and How I retrieve the whole character that separate by each line?, please help me

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the text widget? You can find an answer there.

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import Tk, Text, END

root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.insert(0.0,
"""This is the first line
This is the Second line
This is the Third line""")
text.pack()
lines = text.get(0.0, END).split("\n") #That's the line you need
print(lines)

root.mainloop()
```

CLI output: `['This is the first line', 'This is the Second line', 'This is the Third line', '']`

It leaves a blank item at the end, but you can remove it if you use:

```
lines = text.get(0.0, END).split("\n")[:-1]
```

That will output this:`['This is the first line', 'This is the Second line', 'This is the Third line']`